# Android text overflow

Tags: android, textview, overflow

I have one problem with text overflow.
I have searched all the topics about this problem and tried everything but none work for me(android:singleLine etc..).
To be more specific,text is showing in a single line,in textview,in listview even in alert dialog without custom layout.
The strange fact is that in alert dialog is showing only the first time,if i open again the dialog its ok.But the problem persists in lists and textviews......

The most strange part is that sometimes text is overflowing even in other AVD but later are OK,but in QHD and in my phone(HTC DESIRE) is overflowing.**In Graphical Layout is looking fine in every configuration.**
One layout of the many layouts that have problem is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >

        <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/listview -->

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This problem appeared now,i didnt have it before...i dont know what is causing this because i have update ADT Tools,JDK and i replace my custom Action Bar with ActionBarCompat from ApiDemos.
What is should do?Why this is happening?Maybe is ActionBarCompat fault??

**EDIT:**
I have attached a screenshot of dialog overflow problem(1 of 2)
[image]

Comment: Is there a logcat error? Could you please post it if you do.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
No there isnt any error,everything working fine:(

Comment: You said it crashed on a specific phone. On a particular phone is it possible that you put that phone on debug mode and check what happens to it if it crashes?. That way you can find the problem. Then you can create a solution for all other possible phones.

Comment: No i didnt say it crashed,i said that in QHD AVD and in my phone text is overflowing but not in other AVD or in Graphic Layout

Comment: So what do you really mean by overflow? It goes off the screen? If so then you may have set it to pixels on your layout which layouts itself adjust itself on different views. A solution maybe is to not force the size of a particular view or make it generic.

Comment: Yes goes off the screen.I havent set anywere in my program the height or width in px,everywhere is as it should(dp,sp) and look fine in All AVD except my phone and QHD(emulator) screens...its driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.It was the ActionBarCompat from [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) that make all these problems!!!After so many days trying to find out,was the ActionBar!!!!!!I reported the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26452&thanks=26452&ts=1330983126) and i hope to fix that soon!The problem is that i changed

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
to 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

in styles.xml and cause that bug.

Comment: Thank you Heinrik:) i am grateful for trying to help me...you make me realized that the big change in my app was the Action Bar and i found the solution....

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I suggest using a custom alert dialog since languages other than English is not properly measured. Imagine a box [a] where a holds a character, it gets measured on the width of that character. However android doesn't have the width of other characters other than English. I know this because I also work with other languages on android, it messes up my view so what I did was compromise with the text data. Sorry didn't see your view before posting my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks i will try that for dialog,but before update my program everything was working just fine:(
The dialogs,lists everything was ok with Greek language,now what happened?

Comment: What really happen was the each alphabetical character outside of English is not properly measured. So it ends up messed up I have tested this with Chinese characters and Taiwanese characters. Imagine the letter W. It has a width but if android measures "好" the maximum width would probably be W. So it may be a small scale but it ends up stacking up and it goes off screen(for my case it goes to the second line).

Comment: Lets just say width is not properly calculated for characters other than English.

Comment: Width is not properly measured for languages other than english, or is it non properly measured for non-roman characters ?